# How to copy equations as MathML from Word for Mac 2011

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, clipboard

On Windows Word 2007 and later includes a new style equation editor.  When copying equations they are placed onto the clipboard as MathML (in addition to other formats), and can be pasted into programs such as Mathematica.

Word for Mac 2011 seems to include the same new style equation editor.  How can I copy as MathML in Word for Mac?  (Or if it already does that, how can I access the MathML data on the clipboard on OS X?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Word for Windows, there's a preference setting where you can choose the format of the clipboard contents when you copy an OMML equation (OMML = Office Math Markup Language; i.e., the "new" equation editor). You can choose between MathML and "Linear Format". Based on the way you phrased your question, I assume you know this already (but others may not).

You have the same options in Word 2011 for Mac; you just access it in a different way, but in a way consistent with Mac OS preference settings.

1. In Word 2011, choose **Preferences** from the **Word** menu. In the **Authoring and Proofing Tools** section, choose **Equations**.
2. In the **Equations** Preferences dialog, the **When copying an equation** section gives you this choice. (*Copy linear format* is the default.)

You mention Mathematica, and that's a good example, because using this technique you can copy from Word and paste directly into Mathematica as MathML, which Mathematica understands and can deal with. Most software applications and websites do not understand MathML, but MathType does. If you copy from Word 2011 in this way, then paste it into MathType, you can then use the equation in any of [700+ applications and websites that MathType works with](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/MathType/works_with.asp).

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks!  I did not know there was an option even on Windows.  On Windows I do not need to change any options to be able to paste into Mathematica, and I believe that the equation is copied in several formats at the same time (the clipboard viewer from Windows XP shows this).

Comment: You're right about the multiple formats. On Windows, I count 13 of them, and on the Mac, 19. The multiple formats are because if the app you want to paste into can't accept one format, it may be able to accept another. It's up to the receiving app to "sniff" out the clipboard and take whatever format it can use.

Comment: So the clipboard can hold data in multiple formats on Mac too?  Which program did you use to look at these formats?  On Win I used Clipbrd.exe (I was using WinXP, I hear newer Windows don't have it)

Comment: On Windows I use ClipSpy [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168/ClipSpy) and on the Mac I use Clipboard Viewer 2. ClipSpy is old, but does the job I need it for. Clipboard Viewer 2 is freeware that I got from someone else in our company. Unfortunately I searched but couldn't find the download site. This blog post mentions it and shows screen shots, but doesn't give a link either: [link](http://www.betalogue.com/2010/03/23/clipboard-viewer/).

Comment: Is it maybe [this one](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ClipboardViewer/Introduction/Intro.html)?  I managed to compile it thanks to the convenience of XCode, and it shows several formats, but only as hex/ascii.

Comment: Not sure if that's it, but the Clipboard Viewer 2 I use 1) shows on its About screen a copyright by Apple Inc., and 2) lets you view as ASCII, Hex, or Both. It also gives you a dropdown box to choose between General, Font, Ruler, Find, and Drag clipboards.

Comment: Sounds like the same thing.  Not sure why yours is called Clipboard Viewer 2, maybe it was just compiled like that after some small modifications.  The original is called Clipboard Viewer by default, but comes only as source code so it's not surprising if someone renamed it before compiling.  I guess it also has a teapot icon. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Teapot icon? Hmm. Maybe. I always assumed it was Aladdin's Lamp. I think we're on the right page though.